# Java code that parses a website to return a llist of players does not return anything

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am writing a program in java that will look through a website's html data, find a certain text value, and then return that to me. I am very unfamiliar with working with HTML. Here is the code I have so far, relying on Jsoup.

```java
public static void getPlayerData() throws IOException
    {
        Document page = Jsoup.connect("theURL").get();
        String title = page.title();
        Elements players = page.getElementsByClass("playerName playerNameNoHealth");
        for (Element span : players)
             {
                System.out.println(span.text());
             }
    }
```

The class that I have it looking for is here in the website's structure

```html
<body class="">
<div id-"mcmap" class="dynmap">
<div class ="map leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim">
<div class ="leaflet-map-pane">
<div class ="leaflet-objects-pane">
<div class ="leaflet-marker-pane">
    <div class="Marker playerMarker leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-clickable"style="transform: translate3d(281px, 75px, 0px); z-index: 75;">
        <img class="playerIcon" src="tiles/faces/32x32/(The player's name)"">
        <span class="playerName playerNameNoHealth">(Player's name)</span>
```

I'm not sure if it is not printing the Player's name because it is buried inside more classes, or if I have messed up the syntax for the Jsoup scraping.

Any Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this line instead:

```
Elements players = page.select(".playerName");
```

Comment: Just tried that, but still nothing. I feel like I've just messed up the syntax for "for (Element span : players)" But i can't figure out what i''ve done wrong.

Comment: my code should work.  Maybe you can do a system.out.println of your Document object once you create it, to see if it actually has the html that you think it has

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have checked that to begin with. It's not going deeper into <div id="mcmap"></div>, if you look at the structure i posted you can see it's a few levels within that, but it's just stopping on the "surface" (https://gyazo.com/bf70178c67851bf95288ee39d4f645e7). How can i get it to look inside the dynmap class.

Comment: what's happening is that the javascript which runs on that page is changing the page after it loads.  You want to scrape it AFTER the javascript runs.  There are two general strategies here - you can use chrome inspector to see what API calls it is making and maybe mimic those API calls to get the data you need  OR you can use something like ChromeDriver for Selenium which will actually run the javascript on the page

Comment: In chrome inspector, If I click on XHR and then one of the updates, there's a list of players and where they are. This is the exact information I need. How am I able to get this information into my java program. Should I open a new question since the original problem here has been solved?

Comment: yeah new question might be good.  When you ask the question it might be good to give context - like if you need to be logged in to the game, etc